# Синтаксическая ошибка: "Record, object or class type required на ..."

Tags: delphi, pascal, синтаксис

Есть

```
procedure CreateObjects(const DirPath: string; StrPath, StrDir, StrFile : Tstrings);  
begin  
position:=StrPath.Strings[j].Length-StrFile.Strings[l].Length;  
end.
```

Выдает ошибку

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(274): Record, object or class type required на position:=StrPath.Strings[j].Length-StrFile.Strings[l].Length;
```

Comment: @ivan31, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```
position:=Length(StrPath.Strings[j])-Length(StrFile.Strings[l]);
```

Comment: примите ответ, если он вас устраивает